# How to add some row's specific info to JTexFields using MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtextfield

I have been trying to add a table rows' info to `JTextField` components after clicking with the mouse however it doesn't work. I have used the `DefaultTableModel` and `JTable` as shown below.

Here is the code I have been using.

```java
package scrCode;

import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.SystemColor;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class BorrowABook extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable table;
    private JButton button;
    private JLabel lblBookId;
    private JTextField textFieldBookID;
    private JLabel lblMemberId;
    private JTextField textFieldMemberID;


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    BorrowABook frame = new BorrowABook();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public BorrowABook() {
        setTitle("Library system");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 971, 594);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        String data [][]=null;
        String column []=null;
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        try {
            //code to receive data from the database 
            Connection con=DB.login();
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from book",ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

            ResultSetMetaData rsmd=rs.getMetaData();
            int cols=rsmd.getColumnCount();
            column=new String[cols];
            for(int i=1;i<=cols;i++){
                column[i-1]=rsmd.getColumnName(i);
            }

            rs.last();
            int rows=rs.getRow();
            rs.beforeFirst();

            data=new String[rows][cols];
            int count=0;
            while(rs.next()){
                for(int i=1;i<=cols;i++){
                    data[count][i-1]=rs.getString(i);
                }
                count++;
            }
            con.close();


        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        table = new JTable(data,column);
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table);
        sp.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                int selectedRowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();              
                textFieldBookID.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 0).toString());
                textFieldMemberID.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 1).toString());



            }
        });
        sp.setBounds(5, 5, 936, 402);
        contentPane.add(sp);

        button = new JButton("Back");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                UserSection.main(new String [] {});
                dispose();
            }
        });
        button.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        button.setBackground(SystemColor.info);
        button.setBounds(856, 509, 85, 25);
        contentPane.add(button);

        lblBookId = new JLabel("Book ID:");
        lblBookId.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        lblBookId.setFont(new Font("Sitka Display", Font.BOLD, 22));
        lblBookId.setBounds(28, 420, 141, 29);
        contentPane.add(lblBookId);

        textFieldBookID = new JTextField();
        textFieldBookID.setColumns(10);
        textFieldBookID.setBounds(181, 420, 257, 29);
        contentPane.add(textFieldBookID);

        lblMemberId = new JLabel("Memeber ID:");
        lblMemberId.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        lblMemberId.setFont(new Font("Sitka Display", Font.BOLD, 22));
        lblMemberId.setBounds(28, 469, 141, 29);
        contentPane.add(lblMemberId);

        textFieldMemberID = new JTextField();
        textFieldMemberID.setColumns(10);
        textFieldMemberID.setBounds(181, 469, 257, 29);
        contentPane.add(textFieldMemberID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work", in a **precise** way.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code date to replace the DB. 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 3) This has nothing to do with the IDE. Don't add the tag.

Comment: First of all, I'd never add a MouseListener to the JScrollPane but rather to the JTable itself.

Comment: What exacly is the code supposed to do?

Comment: Doesn't work as that it is not adding the information to the jTestFields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Add your MouseListener to your JTable, not to the JScrollPane. You need notification for when the table has been clicked.
- You're using the wrong model in your listener as you never fill the DefaultTableModel with data. Be safe and get the model in the listener via `table.getModel()`
- No null layouts. While this is not causing your current problem, it forces you to code *against* the library rather than with it.

For example (database code removed for simplicity, null layout removed as well, and posted a MCVE):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class BorrowABook extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable table;
    private JButton button;
    private JLabel lblBookId;
    private JTextField textFieldBookID;
    private JLabel lblMemberId;
    private JTextField textFieldMemberID;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    BorrowABook frame = new BorrowABook();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public BorrowABook() {
        setTitle("Library system");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 971, 594);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        String data[][] = {{"1", "2", "3"}, {"4", "5", "6"}, {"7", "8", "9"}};
        String column[] = {"One", "Two", "Three" };
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        // !! contentPane.setLayout(null);
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        table = new JTable(data, column);
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table);
        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                int selectedRowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
                textFieldBookID.setText(table.getModel().getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 0).toString());
                textFieldMemberID.setText(table.getModel().getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 1).toString());
            }
        });
        //!! sp.setBounds(5, 5, 936, 402);
        contentPane.add(sp);

        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();

        lblBookId = new JLabel("Book ID:");
        lblBookId.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        lblBookId.setFont(new Font("Sitka Display", Font.BOLD, 22));
        bottomPanel.add(lblBookId);

        textFieldBookID = new JTextField();
        textFieldBookID.setColumns(10);
        textFieldBookID.setBounds(181, 420, 257, 29);
        bottomPanel.add(textFieldBookID);

        lblMemberId = new JLabel("Memeber ID:");
        lblMemberId.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        lblMemberId.setFont(new Font("Sitka Display", Font.BOLD, 22));
        lblMemberId.setBounds(28, 469, 141, 29);
        bottomPanel.add(lblMemberId);

        textFieldMemberID = new JTextField();
        textFieldMemberID.setColumns(10);
        textFieldMemberID.setBounds(181, 469, 257, 29);
        bottomPanel.add(textFieldMemberID);

        contentPane.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer. :)